# How to make lines more defined/ clear

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I'm having an issue figuring out how I can make the lines of this image more defined and clear.

I need them to all have the same thickness and color, all vectorized.

I am using illustrator, I can use Photoshop if needed.

[image: example of vector path in Adobe Illustrator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the image already vectorized or do you need to vectorize it? In illustrator you can live trace the image and that may help with the clarity/definition issue.

However if the image is shakily drawn live trace may not be your best bet. You may instead want to trace the entire image using your pen tool with the same weight to the outline stroke and no fill included.

You may want to reference these two youtube videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIzIJZxLX7I - How to live trace

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0t7_X8QH0A - How to use pen tool

I hope that helps!

Comment: I watched the videos and still could not make the lines bolder and more crisp. Some reason my image disappears when I use live trace. Can I send you the image via email so you can have a go? Sorry Im a illustrator noob

Comment: Sure thing! I'll take a go at it, but I can't pen trace a whole image for you, that would take hours for me, but I could get you started so you can see it. erin.s.holman@gmail.com

Comment: @Ashkan Just so you know, that's a weird request to ask for help in this manner on a Questions and Answers site! You won't get better if you let others do your path job, that's for sure.

Comment: @erin I appreciate your generosity! No it will not be necessary for you to spend hours tracing my image, that is absurd! Im playing around with the tracing settings and my image is disappearing, ill let you have a go with it. Maybe im doing something wrong

Comment: @Ashkan: don't forget to 'expand' your live trace after you've traced. Should be right at the top in the bar above your workspace. This converts the Live Trace to paths.

Comment: Thank you everyone, you all are super helpful. I was successful in achieving my goal :)